# Using conditional clause in IFindFluent .SortBy block

Tags: c#, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I'm trying to apply a conditional SortBy to a find as follows:

```
var findFluent = Collection.Find (...)
    .SortBy (record => record.IsActive)
    .SortBy (record => record.Client != null
      ? record.Client.Profile.FirstName 
      : record.Profile.FirstName);
```

However, I'm receiving the following error:

**"Unable to determine the serialization information for record => IIF((record.Client != null), record.Client.Profile.FirstName, record.Profile.FirstName)."**

Do I have to add/implement **IBsonDocumentSerializer** on one of the classes in question or is this operation not possible?

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is impossible in MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up simply adding a new .SortBy () clause based on the logic in the conditional:

```
var findFluent = Collection.Find (...)
   .SortBy (record => record.IsActive)
   .SortBy (record => record.Client.Profile.FirstName) 
   .SortBy (record => record.Profile.FirstName);
```

The driver seems to ignore the sort if a value is null or cannot be evaluated.